# Qt and C++ - undefined reference to slot

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, undefined-reference

I have a build error with a slot in Qt. I have an class which has a public slot:

```
void doSomething();
```

In constructor of this class i do:

```
this->connect( ui->textFrom, SIGNAL(returnPressed()),
               this, SLOT(doSomething()) );
```

I have QLineEdit - textFrom object. The build error is

> ```
> ../moc_mainwindow.cpp:66: undefined reference to `MainWindow::doSomething()'
> ```
>
> :-1: error: collect2: ld returned 1
>   exit status

Help me, please (:

Comment: This doesn't seem like enough information really. If you comment out your connection statement does the error even go away?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

void doSomething(); looks like a snip from the header file, did you implement the slot itself?

Answer (score 1):

quick note about syntax: Usually you would use either

```
connect(from, SIGNAL(sig()), to, SLOT(slot()));
```

which is basically equivalent to

```
QObject::connect(from, SIGNAL(sig()), to, SLOT(slot()));
```

Which you'll do if you're calling from somewhere not inside a QObject.
While this syntax:

```
to->connect(from, SIGNAL(sig()), SLOT(slot()));
```

is also reasonable.
But this syntax:

```
to->connect(from, SIGNAL(sig()), to, SLOT(slot()));
```

is just confusing and duplicates code.

Comment: ...and throws a compiler warning, because 5-arg QObject::connect() is a static method...

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error in a Qt build.

I was adding a slot for the signal *finished*  from  Qprocess - the doco on which says:

```
void QProcess::finished(int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus)
```

My code:

freesound.h

```
void slotPreviewFinished(int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus);
```

freensound.cpp

```
 m_previewProcess = new(Qprocess);
 connect (m_previewProcess ,SIGNAL (finished(int , QProcess::ExitStatus )),this,SLOT(slotPreviewFinished(int , QProcess::ExitStatus)));

 void slotPreviewFinished(int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus)
{
     qDebug()<<"// slotPreviewFinished: "<<exitCode;
}
```

compiling the above generated: 
/home/ttguy/kdenlive/kdenlive_git/build-kdenlive-Desktop-Default/src/moc_freesound.cpp:121: error: undefined reference to `FreeSound::slotPreviewFinished(int, QProcess::ExitStatus)'

And the fix was to prefix my implementation of slotPreviewFinished with FreeSound::

```
void FreeSound::slotPreviewFinished(int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus)
{
     qDebug()<<"// slotPreviewFinished: "<<exitCode;
}
```